# Strange results when using FitText.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Running into a few problems using `FitText.js` - I'm triggering the script in my `<head>` with the following code (I've included everything for reference, and the plan is to minimise this when I'm finished with the design and code layout)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

            var $container = $('#thumbnail-array');

                $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
                    $container.masonry({
                        itemSelector: '.video-thumbnail',
                        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                        gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
                        percentPosition: true
                    });
                });
            });

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('.mobile-close').click(function(e) {
                    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
                    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');

                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                jQuery('.dropdown').click(function(e) {
                    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
                    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');

                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                $(".fittext1").fitText(1.1);
                $(".fittext2").fitText(0.75);
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.overlay').hover(function(){
                    $(this).parent().find('video').get(0).play();
                }, function() {
                    var video = $(this).parent().find('video').get(0);
                    video.pause();
                    video.currentTime = 0;
                });
            });

        </script>
```

The main point of interest there is probably the following:

```
$(".fittext1").fitText(1.1);
$(".fittext2").fitText(0.75);
```

From here I'm applying it to two  elements,  and  which are defined in my CSS as follows:

```
h5 {
    display:inline;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

h6 {
    display:inline;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

and then referenced in my HTML like so:

```
<h5 class="fittext1">Title</h5>
<hr>
<h6 class="fittext2">Subtitle</h6>
```

Now, my understanding is that they should scale with their parent element - however something is up and I can't work out what it is! You can take a look at what is happening here (most noticeable on resize) - http://jameshenry.info/test/test.php

I've tried a couple of different things but can't seem to get all of the text on the rollovers to be consistent, let alone scale up or down in proportion!

I was originally targeting the `.fittext1` and `.fittext2` elements using #ID but switched to class due to multiple instances, however switching between the two doesn't solve the issue.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...And the reason is that FtText.js (as pointed out on the GitHub for the project) doesn't work with inline or span elements - the element that FitText.js is applied to (not a wrapper or container!) needs to be either `absolute`, `block` or `inline-block`

I solved the issue by changing my `<h5>` and `<h6`> tags to display: `inline-block;`